# Android - Setting custom font on substrings in a line

Tags: android, string, emoji

I am having problem in changing font of unicoded Substring in a String line.

I need to match a certain part of string if it contains `:` as it shows that it is an emoji by doing :

`if (part.contains(":"))` where part is a `StringArray` by doing `string.split(" ")`.

I tried using matcher like :

```
            SpannableStringBuilder matchSb = new SpannableStringBuilder(part);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
                    ":([-+\\w]+):");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(matchSb);
            while (matcher.find()){
                String convertPart = Emojione.shortnameToUnicode(matcher.group(1), true);

                matchSb.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), convertPart);
                matchSb.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", emojioneFont), matcher.start()
                        , matcher.end() - 2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            postSb.append(matchSb);
```

But it won't work, not spanning the code, and crash when several emojis are used

Example :

```
1111:relaxed:1111 // Outputs 1111relaxed1111
:relaxed:1111:relaxed: // Outputs nothing, the app crash hehe..
```

From the crash I think.. `matcher.start()` and `end()` doesn't update as matchsb gets its content replaced?

Update :

Error log `replace (11 ... 20) ends beyond length 18`
The `Matcher` thinks that I still have `:relaxed:` whereas it had been replaced with `relaxed`

Comment: Please, provide your log with the cause of the error in it!

Comment: Ah sorry it's very simple tho, it's because the matcher thinks it still has more string than it should have, gonna show it